# Modifications to array also change other array

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine

I have two global multidimensional arrays `@p` and `@p0e` in Perl. This is part of a genetic algorith where I want to save certain keys from `@p` to `@p0e`. Modifications are then made to `@p`. There are several subroutines that make modifications to `@p`, but there's a certain subroutine where on occasion (not on every iteration) a modification to `@p` also leads to `@p0e` being modified (it receives the same keys) although `@p0e` should not be affected.

```
# this is the sub where part of @p is copied to @p0e
sub saveElite {
    @p0e = (); my $i = 0;

    foreach my $r (sort({$a<=>$b} keys $f{"rank"})) {
        if ($i<$elN) {
            $p0e[$i] = $p[$f{"rank"}{$r}]; # save chromosome
        }
        else {last;}
        $i++;
    }
}

# this is the sub that then sometimes changes @p0e
sub mutation {
    for (my $i=0; $i<@p; $i++) {
        for (my $j=0; $j<@{$p[$i]}; $j++) {
            if (rand(1)<=$mut) { # mutation
                $p[$i][$j] = mutate($p[$i][$j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought maybe I'd somehow created a reference to the original array rather than a copy, but because this unexpected behaviour doesn't happen on every iteration this shouldn't be the case.

Comment: This would really benefit from some sample data. And using `strict` and `warnings`. As it is, it's really hard to tell if there's a even a problem in this piece of code you've quoted, as it could easily just not be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$j = $f{"rank"}{$r};
$p0e[$i] = $p[$j];
```

`$p[$j]` is an array *reference*, which you can think of as pointing to a particular list of data at a particular memory address. The assignment to `$p0e[$i]` also tells Perl to let the `$i`-th row of `@p0e` also refer to that same block of memory. So when you later make a change to `$p0e[$i][$k]`, you'll find the value of `$p[$j][$k]` has changed too.

To fix this, you'll want to assign a *copy* of `$p[$j]`. Here is one way you can do that:

```
$p0e[$i] = [ @{$p[$j]} ];
```

`@{$p[$j]}` deferences the array reference and `[...]` creates a new reference for it, so after this statement `$p0e[$i]` will have the same contents with the same values as `$p[$j]` but point to a different block of memory.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem will *probably* be this:

```
$p0e[$i] = $p[$f{"rank"}{$r}]; # save chromosome
```

Because it looks like `@p` is a multi-dimensional array.

The problem is - the way perl 'does' multi dimensional arrays is via arrays of references. So if you copy an inner array, you do so by reference.

E.g.:

```
#!c:\Strawberry\perl\bin
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @list = ( [ 1, 2, 3 ],
             [ 4, 5, 6 ],
             [ 7, 8, 9 ], );

             print Dumper \@list; 

my @other_list;
push ( @other_list, @list[0,1] ); #make a sub list of two rows;
print Dumper \@other_list; 


### all looks good.
## but if we:

print "List:\n";
print join ("\n",@list),"\n";
print "Other List:\n";
print join ("\n", @other_list),"\n";

$list[1][1] = 9;

print Dumper \@other_list;
```

You will see that by changing an element in `@list` we also modify `@other_list` - and if we just `print` them we get:

```
List:
ARRAY(0x2ea384)
ARRAY(0x12cef34)
ARRAY(0x12cf024)
Other List:
ARRAY(0x2ea384)
ARRAY(0x12cef34)
```

Note the duplicate numbers - that means you have the same reference.

The easiest way of working around this is by using `[]` judicously:

```
push ( @other_list, [@{$list[0]}], [@{$list[1]}] ); #make a sub list of two rows;
```

This will then insert anonymous arrays (new ones) containing the dereferenced elements of the list.

Whilst we're at it though - please turn on `strict` and `warnings`. They will save you a lot of pain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's an array of arrays. The first level array stores only references to the inner arrays, if you modify the inner array, it's changed in both arrays - they both refer to the same array. [Clone](http://p3rl.org/Clone) the deep copy instead of creating a shallow one.